# New proofs of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, soft-question, big-list, alternative-proof

Apart from the standard one, are there any other proofs of the Fundamental Theorem of **Calculus** which have been published recently?

Comment: The FTC is kind of a trivial thing for a research mathematicians to be working on. I doubt people are still seriously looking for and/or publishing proofs beyond the standard ones.

Comment: What is "the standard one"
?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Proof_of_the_first_part

Comment: Why would you want anything other than the theorem posed as is?

Comment: Yes, it would really help if you described the "standard one."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It should be the one based on the mean value theorem for integrals.